# Show that $||x+y||\cdot||x-y||\le||x||^2+||y||^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

The question is to show that for any $x,y \in\Re^n$

$||x+y||\cdot||x-y||\le||x||^2+||y||^2$

with equality if and only if $\langle x,y \rangle= 0.$

I have that $||x+y||^2=||x||^2+2 \langle x,y \rangle+||y||^2$ , which helps me prove equality but I'm lost on how to show this and show that the inequality part.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in the same way that you got your formula, notice that

$$\|x - y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 - 2 \langle x, y \rangle + \|y\|^2$$

so that

$$\|x + y\|^2 \|x - y\|^2 = (\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2)^2 - 4 \langle x, y \rangle^2.$$

What can you conlude from this?

Comment: Thanks, Micah take a look at the sqrt and you get $\sqrt{(||x||^2+||y||^2)^2-A}$ when A is constant, it was easier for me to look at it this way